# how to make nvidia/cuda/tensorflow/keras installation work

Tags: nvidia, software-installation, compiling, cuda, tensorflow

I have recently started setting up an environment to begin Machine Learning. I have Win10, an i9 processor, GeForce GTX 1650. I had Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, and installed vcxsrv. I was able to install anaconda navigator, and from there Keras and Tensorflow. I was able to use Spyder and start running simple models. I then switched to Tensorflow-GPU and installed CUDA and GraphViz. I'm not sure at this point if the correct dependencies are in place, if the builds are correct, or if it's actually using the GPU. .show() and print() are not displaying images in spyder.
I'm now seeing errors and messages, and I'm unsure how to fix them. I edited PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in .bashrc Any assistance in where to look to fix this is greatly appreciated.

```
NotFoundError: /home/benny/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/core/kernels/libtfkernel_sobol_op.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringB5cxx11EPNS_15OpKernelContextEb
 (28, 28, 1) 10
2021-01-25 07:17:48.726718: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-25 07:17:48.726999: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/benny/rdkit-Release_2020_09_3/rdkit:/home/benny/rdkit-Release_2020_3/rdkit/lib::/home/benny/boost_1_75_0/libs:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:}
2021-01-25 07:17:48.727015: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2021-01-25 07:17:48.727030: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (Laptop): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2021-01-25 07:17:48.727253: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-01-25 07:17:48.728456: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-25 07:17:48.844844: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-01-25 07:17:48.845218: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU
```

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: 2004.2020.812.0, 20.04.1 LTS